# How to understand a lambda function in a library

Tags: python, lambda, alpha-shape

#### Question

Here's a function to calculate alphashape of a set of points. It's from [the documentation of the library 'alphashape'](https://alphashape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#using-a-varying-alpha-parameter).

```
points_2d = [(0., 0.), (0., 1.), (1., 1.), (1., 0.),(0.5, 0.25), (0.5, 0.75), (0.25, 0.5), (0.75, 0.5)]

alpha_shape = alphashape(
    points_2d,
    lambda ind, r: 1.0 + any(np.array(points_2d)[ind][:,0] == 0.0))
```

I don't understand how the `lambda` function above works in the following context (an excerpt from [library's source code](https://alphashape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/alphashape/alphashape.html#alphashape)).

Specifically, my questions are:

- where does variable `r` come from?
- what does `[:,0]` mean?

#### Context

```
def alphashape(points: Union[List[Tuple[float]], np.ndarray],
               alpha: Union[None, float] = None):
    coords = np.array(points)
    for point_indices, circumradius in alphasimplices(coords):
        if callable(alpha):
            resolved_alpha = alpha(point_indices, circumradius)
```

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

def alphasimplices(points: Union[List[Tuple[float]], np.ndarray]) -> \
        Union[List[Tuple[float]], np.ndarray]:
    coords = np.asarray(points)
    tri = Delaunay(coords)

    for simplex in tri.simplices:
        simplex_points = coords[simplex]
        try:
            yield simplex, circumradius(simplex_points)
```

```
def circumradius(points: Union[List[Tuple[float]], np.ndarray]) -> float:
    points = np.asarray(points)
    return np.linalg.norm(points[0, :] - np.dot(circumcenter(points), points))
```

```
def circumcenter(points: Union[List[Tuple[float]], np.ndarray]) -> np.ndarray:
    points = np.asarray(points)
    num_rows, num_columns = points.shape
    A = np.bmat([[2 * np.dot(points, points.T),
                  np.ones((num_rows, 1))],
                 [np.ones((1, num_rows)), np.zeros((1, 1))]])
    b = np.hstack((np.sum(points * points, axis=1),
                   np.ones((1))))
    return np.linalg.solve(A, b)[:-1]
```

Comment: The function is being passed as a parameter.  Within `alphashape`, the function is called `alpha`.  When you see `alpha(point_indicies, circumradius)`, it's calling that lambda just as if it had been defined with `def alpha(ind, r):`.

Comment: The type annotation for `alphashape` is completely wrong -- it looks like it's taking a `Callable`, not an `Optional[float]`.  A `lambda` is just a quick way to construct a callable.

Comment: @Samwise I omit a line of code from the source. It check if the variable `alpha` is callable first. I revised the question.

Comment: "where does variable r come from?" it's a *parameter to the function*. It is important to understand, `lambda` expressions just create regular functions. They are never *required*, they are syntactic sugar. You could use a function definition statement to create the same thing.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks. I added 2 more specific questions. Could you please have another look.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga answered the first question.  `x[:,0]` is a `numpy` thing that extracts the first "plane" of the array.  That is, it creates a new one-dimensional array containing all of the elements where the second coordinate is 0.

Comment: @TimRoberts I understand `x[:,0]`, but `np.array(points_2d)[ind][:,0]` seems a bit different. When I executed this line of code, I got an error message: `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed`.

Comment: Yep, that must be a mistake in their tutorial.  You'd need `[0]`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Curiously, the [tutorial](https://alphashape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#using-a-varying-alpha-parameter) works. Any idea why it could work?

Comment: You tried it and it didn't work, right?  Isn't that what the whole question is about?

Comment: @TimRoberts The tutorial itself works. But when I extracted that code line and executed it, the error came in. It seems that that line code needs some context burying in the library, which I don't quite understand.